# How to get java.sql.Date Object with full time timestamp

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, date

Below is my code snippet,

```
for(int i = 0;i < 24;i++) {
Calendar calHourlyObj = new GregorianCalendar(2013,05,05);
calHourlyObj.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, i);
java.sql.Date sqldate1 = new java.sql.Date((calHourlyObj.getTime()).getTime());
System.out.println("sqldate1"+sqldate1);
}
```

Here am having a calendar object for 'calHourlyObj ' a specific date range,for which am setting the calendar object to every hour of the day within the loop.When i assign this calHourlyObj to  java.util.Date i get the date with full timestamp in desired format.But i have to pass this date object to a stored procedure which accepts date only in java.sql.Date format.If i assign my  calHourlyObj to java.sql.Date then the timestamp is lost,and every time date is set to the first hour.

How could i get java.sql.Date with full timestamp.

Alternatively i have tried

```
java.sql.Timestamp sqldate1 = new java.sql.Timestamp((calHourlyObj.getTime()).getTime());
cstmt.setTimeStamp(1,sqldate1 )
```

and

```
java.sql.Timestamp sqldate1 = new java.sql.Timestamp((calHourlyObj.getTime()).getTime());
cstmt.setObject(1,sqldate1,TYPES.Oracle);
```

But here am not getting any compilation error.But my stored procedure is not behaving as expected.How could i acheieve java.sql.Date object with full timestamp?

Comment: `java.sql.Date` doesn't have time component. What exactly is wrong with   the first`java.sql.Timestamp` snippet?

Comment: The problem is my stored procedure is picking the timestamp object,but after fetching its not populating any records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must create your column with `TIMESTAMP` type and Oracle `DATE` resolves to the second only. Do you really need millisecond precision? What is your OJDBC verion?

Anyway, doing `setTimestamp(...,new Timestamp(System.currentMillis()))` is the right thing to do.